# Eclipse: include source code while exporting as runnable jar

Tags: eclipse, jar

I understand how to include other needed libraries or outside resources while creating a runnable .jar file in eclipse, but what I don't see is an option to also include the src .java files as well.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `Export --> Jar File`  dialog you have the option to incluse source files and resources.

[image]

To make runnable a standard Jar File you only need to add/include an appropiate [MANIFEST.MF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) on your own ...

Comment: Do you happen to know if there an explicit reason I need to do this myself vs. an interface option? Is this not a common request?

Comment: The Runanble Jar dialog just doesn't contains that option, so you can workaround exporting as standard JAr File and includiding the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: It's still not a replacement for exporting an executable jar. Exporting a normal jar doesn't allow you to add dependent libraries into the jar or the destination folder.

Comment: Point to note: The `Export --> Runnable Jar` Does not have these options.

Answer (score 2):

Export to Runnable jar.
Open the Runnable Jar with WinRAR.
Click Add button, select the src.zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answer is very late, but for those who still read this:

Eclipse has this option. You probably just did not notice it. I haven't checked since what version, Eclipse Luna has it for sure.

- `Export --> Jar File`
- then do not click `Finish`, but click `Next`.
- You have more options there.
- You will probably have to click `Next` twice to get to the `Main Class` selection.

Comment: Since ancient versions