# Java - Export Project to Open Source

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to develop my Java program, and I was wondering if their is a way to export it as open source software. For example, KeePass developed using C#, allows you to download a zip file. When you unzip it, you can double click the icon and start using the software, and still open and see the code. Is it possible to do that in Java with eclipse?

Comment: a common way is to push it to github or bitbucket

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483771/eclipse-include-source-code-while-exporting-as-runnable-jar) may help.

Comment: @njzk2 - Thanks, but what I'm after is, how do I go about exporting it from eclipse, so that I double click an icon and start using the software. Just like keepass.

Comment: @DSquare - Thanks, I think this is what I maybe after.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: I don't know what keepass is, nor do I use it (nor apparently could I even if I wanted to). I you want to open-source your code, you have to publish it. Unless you host it yourself, pushing your source repo to github is the easiest way to go. Push the binary with the tags, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at websites such as [`SourceForge`](http://sourceforge.net/). Through it you should be able to upload your source and make it available to thrid parties. Others include [`Google Code`](https://code.google.com/hosting/) and [`GitHub`](https://github.com/).

EDIT: As per your comment, you would need to turn your JAR file into an executable JAR. Please check [this](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm) eclipse page to see how this can be achieved.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to export my java project, so that it includes a way to use the software, and still be able to look at the code. Just like KeePass.

Comment: AH! I think you nailed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. Click File --> Export... --> Java, JAR File or Runnable JAR file --> Next and then select option "Export Java source files and resources". This will create a JAR file that can be executed, but people interested can also browse the source code which will be included within.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing like "export as open source". Publish you source code (look for a fitting license though), use a version control system like `git`, publish it to public repositories like [github](https://help.github.com/categories/bootcamp/). You can also ship your compiled binaries as a download through these public sites then.

If you're just looking for an executable version of your program, your question is a bit off. It strongly depends on the technology you're working with and of course the language. For a standard Java project you can find that option under `File --> Export --> Java --> Runnable JAR File`. I'm sure there's a way to include the sources in the wizard, but the preferable way to open source your software is what I wrote first, since then you can socialize your project.