# Ho to read .java file in executable jar

Tags: java, io, executable-jar

I'm using this code to load a .java file and do the search:

```
public class FindClassName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MOJ.Logger");

        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("./src/string/FindClassName.java"))){
            String pattern = "class\\s*(\\w+)\\s*";
            List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(line);
                while(matcher.find()){
                    list.add(matcher.group(1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }catch(IOException exception){
            logger.info("Couldn't read file");
        }
    }


    static class CHUJ{

    }

}
```

it works but when I export this to executable .jar file then It can't load file to reader. I've read that I need to use:

```
FindClassName.class.getResource("FindClassName.java");
```

but this gives me NullPointerException. I tried many different approaches but still couldn't load that .java file to reader with getResource() or getResourcesAsStream().

I know there are tons of questions like that, but I couldn't find the solution.

**EDIT**

this is strange, this code now runs in executable jar(with resources included) but not within eclipse... why? is there a better way?

```
public class FindClassName {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MOJ.Logger");

        //String directory = "./src/string/FindClassName.java"; //to będzie działać w eclipsie, ale jak zrobisz z tego jar to wszystkie pliki .java zostaną skompilowane na .class
        InputStream directory = FindClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("FindClassName.java");

        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(directory))){
            String pattern = "class\\s*(\\w+)\\s*";
            List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(line);
                while(matcher.find()){
                    list.add(matcher.group(1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }


    static class CHUJ{

    }

}
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't work because all `java` files will be compiled into `class` files.

Comment: is there any way to do what original program does in executable jar?

Comment: Have you tried giving the full path to the file?

Comment: You should be able to include the source files in the jar (I don't remember the details).  You should then be able to find the .java file by including the fully qualified name of the .java file (e.g. com/mycompany/myproject/mypackage/FindClassName.java)

Comment: Including source files described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483771/eclipse-include-source-code-while-exporting-as-runnable-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

When you create an excecutable JAR (Actually any jar) all the .java files are compiled and transformed into .class files that can be used then by the JVM.

**Solution:**

One solution is to include the source code directory as additinal resource directory (Not a normal usecase):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

See [this link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-generate-and-deploy-a-source-jar-file-for-my-project.html) for more information or [this video using Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynXjh6jbeQ0)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
C:\>java -jar JarFileExample.jar
package com.mycompany.myproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class JarFileExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                InputStream is = JarFileExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/myproject/JarFileExample.java");
                writeFileToConsole(is);
        }

        private static void writeFileToConsole(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                for(String str = reader.readLine(); str != null; str = reader.readLine()) {
                        System.out.println(str);
                }
                reader.close();
        }

}

C:\>
```

The source code can easily be included in the jar file but depends on the tool you are using to create the jar.  I used eclipse and basically the method described here: [Eclipse: include source code while exporting as runnable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483771/eclipse-include-source-code-while-exporting-as-runnable-jar)

Comment: please see the edit, maybe you can explain it to me also.

Comment: Try adding a / to the file name (e.g. /FindClassName.java instead of FindClassName.java).  Is there a package definition for this class?

Comment: slash doesn't help... what you mean package definition? this file is inside package named "string"

Comment: What is the very first line in the .java file.  It should be something like: package com.mycompany.myproject;

Comment: Try something like this: getResourceAsStream("/string/FindClassName.java");

Comment: If you unzip the jar file (you might need to rename it to .zip first) is the .java file in the resulting folder?  Is it in a folder called "string"?